# jquery not recognizing new class after .removeClass().addClass()?

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

Perhaps I am doing this incorrectly/inefficiently but this isn't working for me:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('li.taglink').click(function(){
        alert('clicked tag');
        $userClicked = $(this).html();
        $('#holder').children('div').each(function () { 
            $('li.taglinkcurrent').removeClass('taglinkcurrent').addClass('taglink');                                       
            $x = $(this).attr("tags");
            ele = $x.split(',');
            for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) 
            {
            if ($userClicked == ele[i]) {$(this).show(495); break;} 
                                    else {$(this).hide(495);}   
            }
        });
        $(this).removeClass('taglink').addClass('taglinkcurrent');
    });

    $('li.taglinkcurrent').click(function(){
        alert('clicked current');
        $('li.taglinkcurrent').removeClass('taglinkcurrent').addClass('taglink');                               
        $('li.taglink').show(495);
    });

});
```

The page contains divs with "tags" attributes that contains several tags. I also have an unordered list, with each li element containing the individual tags. When a user clicks one of the li elements, it shows all the divs that have that tag, and hides everything else. If a user clicks that same li element, it then shows everything once again. I added in the alerts to test what was going on, and every time I click a link it pops up "clicked link" even when the li had its class switched to .taglinkcurrent. Any ideas of what I've done wrong?

Comment: Your code needs a clean up. You have the same alert in both events. Maybe you could post your HTML in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: You know that $('.class_name') iterates through the DOM to find your objects... and calling it twice iterates twice... right? Saving the results into a variable would skip the reiterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the event is attributed to each li on load, and the subsequent class changes doesn't unbind the event.
But you can easily fix this this way, I think :

```
$('li').click(function() {
    if ( $(this).hasClass("taglink") ) {
        alert("clicked tag");
        ...
    } else if ( $(this).hasClass("taglinkcurrent") ) {
        alert('clicked current');
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are binding to the `click()` event when you first run the code, so the `"taglink"` class is the only one in play.

To have the function change depending on changes to the dom use the `on()` method instead:

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(document).on("click", "li.taglink", function() { 
  // ... 
});
```

There are lots of caveats the with the `on()` method however - see the documentation above for more details.

Edit: Changed 'live' to 'on' as from v1.7 that is the preferred method.

Comment: Or rather: **for more details look at: http://api.jquery.com/on** and elements delegation. (jQ 1.7+ says: `.live()` = deprecated ; `.on()` = COOL! )

Comment: For some reason I couldn't get this working? Could have been a syntax problem but I wasn't getting any alerts. I worry about the 'caveats' you mention too, and Matthieu provided a working fix that seems simple enough for my purposes.